# C# Dictionary is empty after calling new function

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

I have a question regarding a C# Dictionary in a class i made.
The problem is that when I fill the dictionary with the setValue(String str, object obj) everything is working fine. But when I request a value from the dictionary (for example getX()) debuggins tells me the dictionaty count = 0.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
class KRLFrame: KRLStruct
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    public KRLFrame(String name)
        : base(name, new String[] { "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C" })
    {

    }

    public KRLFrame setX(double d)
    {
        dict["X"] = d;
        return this;
    }

    public Double getX()
    {
        return dict["X"];
    }


    //@Overrides
    public override void setValue(String str, object obj)
    {
        String s = Convert.ToString(obj);
        s = s.Replace('.', ',');
        dict[str] = Convert.ToDouble(s);
    }

    public override Object getValue()
    {
        return dict;
    }
}
```

The setValue function is called from a underlying class.
The main class calls these functions like this:

```
 KRLFrame base1 = new KRLFrame("BASE_DATA[1]");
 base1.setX(10);
 client.readVariable(base1); //Code for reading a variable, in different class
 Console.WriteLine("BASE_DATA[1]: " + base1.getStringValue());
 Double d = base1.getX();
```

In my opinion the base1 of type KRLFrame will contain a Dictionary called dict that will be linked to base1. therefor calling base1.getX() should result in the Dictionary value with key "X" right?

Thanks for the help! ;)

KRLStruct class uses folowing function:

```
abstract class KRLStruct : KRLVariable
{
    private String[] nodes;

    public KRLStruct(String name, String[] nodes)
        :base(name)
    {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
```

KRLVariable is like this:

```
 abstract class KRLVariable
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String strValue;

    public KRLVariable(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = rnd.Next(1, 999999) ;
    }
```

Comment: could you post KRLStruct class?

Comment: There is no usage of Class1 in code which you have provided

Comment: How does `KRLFrame` relate to `Class1`

Comment: This code lacks the required [mcve] to understand it

Comment: I just created this in LinqPad without the base class and it works.

Comment: Sorry! I made a new class called Class1 for the example. It should be called KRLFrame.

Comment: Something seems off, why is the base class called a struct? That cant happen

Comment: Let's try with this. If you comment out the line _client.readVariable(base1);_ and the following one, what happens?

Comment: I added code from the other classes in my question! The struct maybe is confusing, but this is a structure for variables in the systems this program communicates with.

Comment: @Steve I removed the code and the resulting d gives 10! The readvariable overwrites the Dictionary perhaps?

Comment: That's what I mean for _lacks a MCVE_. You have the culprit now. That lines changes your underlying structures in a disruptive way. What do you do in that method?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that Steve. The underlying code is quite large, because it is used by multiple other classes. But the fact that I can see the Dictionary being filled with the function setValue(...) made me realise that somewhere these values are not stored correctly. I'm not that familiar with C# programming so I thought it would be a simple protected/private/public issue. What woud you advise to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seams ok but you have to protect your dictionary from external access. I think the root cause of your problem is this.

Change your code

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

Also modify the `getValue()` method like this:

```
public override Object getValue()
{
    return dict.ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => m.Value);
}
```

This will give back a snapshot from your dictionary and protect your original one.
It has a little overhead for GC (extra dictionary creation) but it is negligible.